# How do i get platinum?

Tags: harvest-moon-3d-a-new-beginning

I've been using the mine for a while, i only have the iron hammer and iron axe, while mining i've upgraded almost all my tools to gold and got a couple of diamonds to upgrade the gold tools to ultimate however the last thing i need is black lumber

i have plenty of black branches but the iron axe wont cut them and i havn't found a single peice of platinum in the mine despite the fact i've gotten diamonds, i've been visiting the mine everyday for about a month

i am wondering where i can find platinum to upgrade my axe to then upgrade my gold tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Platinum is gotten from the mine.  Sounds like you've gotten unlucky in that, though.

What I do, if there's an item I really need from the mine, is I save the game before I do my mining, and reset if I don't get it.  The items you get are random, so you can abuse this to ensure you get at least one item you want.